# Android ActionBar TabNavigation switching between tabs clears View

Tags: android, tabs, navigationbar

I'm trying to convert my app to TabNavigation layout using [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html) tutorial. First and last tab layout are always the same(just content changes), only second is different in every app. So I want from second tab manage others, e.g. in first one is imageView and from second tab I can firstTab.imageView.setImageResources(/somePic) to display some picture. It works fine but I noticed that app starts on tab1 and show picture, then I switch to tab2 and back to tab1, it's still there, but when I go to tab3->tab1 or tab3->tab2->tab1 the pictire is gone, so I have to go tab2->tab1
again to set the picture. Why is it happening and how to avoid that? I'm a begginer in android so thanks a lot for any help.

TabActivity:

```
public class TabActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar = getActionBar();
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    //Add New Tab
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Podgląd").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Dane").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Rozwiązanie").setTabListener(tabListener));
}
```

}

TabPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        //Fragement for Android Tab
        return new Review();
    case 1:
       //Fragment for Ios Tab
        return new Data();
    case 2:
        //Fragment for Windows Tab
        return new Solution();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3; //No of Tabs
}
}
```

Data class(second tab)

```
public class Data extends Fragment {
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View ios = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ios_frag, container, false);
        ((TextView)ios.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("iOS");
        Review.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        return ios;
```

}}

Review class(first tab)

```
public class Review extends Fragment {
public static ImageView imageView;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_frag, container, false);
        //((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Android");
        imageView = (ImageView)android.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        return android;
```

}
}

Solution class(third tab)

```
public class Solution extends Fragment {
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View windows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.windows_frag, container, false);
        ((TextView)windows.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Windows");
        return windows;
```

}}

I have read now about sending data with Bundle cause it saves app state but it doesn't work, I think it's because tab classes doesn't extends Activity, am I wrong?

Comment: post your code please